# Real-device error mitigation with qiskit

Tags: qiskit, error-correction, error-mitigation

I'm trying to do error mitigation in IBM-Q quantum computers with qiskit. I followed the tutorial [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/noise/3_measurement_error_mitigation.html). My thought was that in order to make sure that I'm correcting the qubits that I'm actually using in my circuits, I should specify the backend and qubits to make sure that the qubits used in my actual circuit and obtaining the correcting matrix are the same. I asked [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12045/specifying-qubits-to-achieve-measurement-error-mitigation-on-qiskit) and followed along, but I have encountered some problems. Here is the part that is causing problem:

```
    qreg = qk.QuantumRegister(7)
    layout = {qreg[0]: 12, 
              qreg[1]: 11,
              qreg[2]: 13, 
              qreg[3]: 17, 
              qreg[4]: 14, 
              qreg[5]: 12, 
              qreg[6]: 6}


    ########## error mitigation ##########

    meas_calibs, state_labels = complete_meas_cal(
            qubit_list=[0, 1, 2], qr=qreg, circlabel='mcal') 
    print(meas_calibs[0])

    # This line below is causing error if I add "initial_layout" in both qk.compiler.transpile and qk.execute
    qk.compiler.transpile(meas_calibs, backend=_backend, initial_layout=layout)
```

I receive the error

```
qiskit.dagcircuit.exceptions.DAGCircuitError: 'not a DAG'
```

whenever I specify the layout. I googled about this error but found nothing. So my question is, what does this error mean? What have I done wrong and how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assigned 2 virtual qubits to the same physical qubit, both `qreg[0]` and `qreg[5]` are assigned to physical qubit `12`. If you change one of these to be a different physical qubit, it should work.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Sorry for making such a stupid mistake :(

Comment: No worries at all, we all do it :)